# Constructing a Hyperelliptic Curve with given characteristic polynomial

Tags: elliptic-curves, hilbert-polynomial, complex-multiplication

According to this [lecture](http://www.skidmore.edu/fq12/uploads/Eisentraeger.pdf), how can a hyperelliptic curve (of genus $2$) be constructed in the following example?

Let $C: f(x)=y^2$ (where $f(x)$ is of degree $5$) be the curve we want to construct over the finite field $\mathbb F_{59}$.

Suppose the characteristic polynomial $P$ of $C$ is given by $x^4 + 3x^3 + 99x^2 + 177x + 3481$. Let $J(C)$ denote the Jacobian group of $C$.

From this [article](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2011/437541/), We know that $|J|$ is either  $P(1) = 3761$ or $P(-1) = 3401$. Similar to elliptic curves, $C$ should have Complex Multiplication or CM.

With elliptic curves, one needs to computer the Hilbert Class polynomial $H$ of the characteristic polynomial (a quadratic), then find an elliptic curve whose $j$-invariant is equal a root of $H$.

In the hyperelliptic case, the number field obtained by the characteristic polynomial $P$ has class number $4$, so the Hilbert class polynomial $H$ of $P$ should also be of degree $4$.

The first problem I run into is computing $H$. Secondly, assuming we know $H$, is there a function similar to the $j$-invariant that can be used to calculate the curve? The first lecture mentions Igusa invariants, yet there is no explicit formula to compute such an invariant of a hyperelliptic curve (analogous to $j$-invariants of elliptic curves).

In summary, the Jacobian of our curve $C$ over finite field $F_{59}$ must have cardinality $3401$ or $3761$, and the characteristic polynomial of $C$ is $P$. The problem is constructing $C$ as mentioned above.

Any suggestions? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, i had a hard time to put together the pieces of the puzzle, please add some more pointed information in the question. My main problem was that the question links to two different sources, without an explicit page reference (for notations, algorithm, properties), so the reader must understand them as a whole, then relate them to the question. The given curve is in fact not given. We have only the field characteristic $p$ or $l$ equal to $59$ of the base field. We need to construct $C$ so that the Jacobian $J(C)$ defined over $\Bbb F_p$ has some properties. The pair...

Comment: ... The pair $(l,N_1,N_2)$ is not explicitly given, but it should lead to $s_1=-3$ and $s_2=99$, as specified on page 4 at the bottom in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405305.pdf . So we have the polynomial constructed from $l,s_1,s_2$ $$x^4 -s_1x^3+s_2x^2-ls_1x+l^2\ ,$$which is the polynomial given in the question. But this polynomial does not generate a CM field, if my sage computations are correct. Later on in the above arXiv paper we have an example in §7, the example works with $K=\Bbb Q(a)$, $a=\sqrt{3\sqrt{13}-13}$ with minpoly $x^4 + 26x^2 + 52$, this is the CM field, and the $\psi$...

Comment: ... the $\psi$ from §7 looks rather like a "reversed" characteristic polynomial. The construction is very specific, the sources use $K$ not really in a clear setting. Is there a clear description of the algorithm with a clear example? Which is the source for the present question?